# Swift UIImage Array from JSON URL

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uiimage

I try to create an Array of UIImages from a URL Array received from a JSON Request to show them afterwards in a UITableView.
But somehow my UIImage Array stays Empty and is not receiving any Data. 
The other Arrays for example memeURL are receiving all Data correct but memePics.count stays on 0.

Would be great if someone could show me what i am doing wrong.
Also if for this task there is a better way on how to do it - it would be also appreciated!

Var:

```
var memePics: [UIImage] = []
```

Loop to add Images to Array:

```
while(i < memeURL.count) {
            MemeAPI.requestAPIImageFile(url: memeURL[i]) { (image, error) in
                guard let image = image else {
                    print("PIC IS NIL")
                    return
                }
                self.memePics.append(image)
                i+=1
            }
        }
```

RequestAPIImageFile Function:

```
class func requestAPIImageFile(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return}
            let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
            completionHandler(downloadedImage, nil)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting images from two different api's?

Comment: When you say images are empty, does it show ""PIC IS NIL" ?

Comment: Not related: `while(i < memeURL.count) { doSomethingAsync {i+1} }` => DispatchGroup, enter, leave, notify.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: No its the same API just 2 different Functions - first (not showed in my example) for receiving Data like URL of the IMG, Name etc - this one is working fine. And the other Function for Downloading the Image from URL. 

koen: No - the Console does not Print out an Error or my Custom Print which means the guard seems to pass fine.

Comment: I still don't understand, in the first closure for the MemeAPI call you are adding the result to an UIImage array and in the second closure for URLSession you are creating an UIImage instance so to me it looks like you are getting your images from 2 different sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add plus line out of callback

```
  self.memePics.append(image)
  }
  i+=1
```

and use DispatchGroup to be notified on finish like

```
let g = DispatchGroup()
memeURL.forEach {  
        g.enter()
        MemeAPI.requestAPIImageFile(url:$0) { (image, error) in
            guard let image = image else {
                print("PIC IS NIL")
                return
            }
            self.memePics.append(image) 
            g.leave()
        }
} 
g.notify(queue:.main) {
   print("All done")
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much it is working now! 
I´ve now put both of my Functions in the Dispatch Group and the arrays works fine. 
Still have 1 Problem but I will create another Post for this - Thanks again!